Issues Deploying Multiple Azure Resources with ARM Template
I need you help with an ARM template issue I'm facing. Here's a brief summary:
I am working on creating a template for deploying a resource group and several resources related to Azure Machine Learning. Since I need to deploy multiple instances within the same subscription, I'm using a subscription-level template.
I want to format the names of various components consistently. For example, given a workspace name like my_project-Name, I need to transform it into (some users do not follow the usage of '-' or '_'):

hyphenWorkSpaceName: my-project-name
validWorkSpaceName: myprojectname
workSpaceFullName: my-project-name

The reason for these transformations is that groups are usually named as gr-name, workspaces as mlw-project-XX, storage accounts as stmlwprojectXXX, and other services as mlw-project-XX--AB.
Here's the template I’m using:
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "grPrefix":{
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue":"gr-mlw-"
        },
        "rgLocation": {
            "type": "string",
            "allowedValues":[
                "eastus2",
                "swedencentral",
                "taiwannorth"
            ],
            "defaultValue":"eastus2"
        },
        "workSpacePreffix":{
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue":"mlw-",
            "metadata":{
                "description":" Machine Learning Workspace Prefix"
            }
        },
        "workSpaceName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "WorkSpace Name"
            }
        },
        "deploymentName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "IacDSGroupResourceDeploymentV1",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "description"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
        "hypenWorkSpaceName":"[toLower(replace(parameters('workSpaceName'), '_', '-'))]",
        "validWorkSpaceName":"[toLower(replace(variables('hypenWorkSpaceName'), '-', ''))]",
        "resourceGroupName":"[concat(parameters('grPrefix'), variables('hypenWorkSpaceName'))]",
        "workSpaceFullName":"[concat(parameters('workSpacePreffix'), variables('hypenWorkSpaceName'))]",
        "storageAccountName":"[concat('st', variables('validWorkSpaceName'))]",
        "keyVaultName":"[concat(variables('hypenWorkSpaceName'), '-kv')]",
        "applicationInsightsName":"[concat(variables('hypenWorkSpaceName'), '-ai')]",
        "containerRegistryName":"[concat(variables('hypenWorkSpaceName'), 'cr')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2024-03-01",
            "name": "[variables('resourceGroupName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('rgLocation')]",
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2024-03-01",
            "name":"[parameters('deploymentName')]",
            "resourceGroup":"[variables('resourceGroupName')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/', variables('resourceGroupName'))]"
            ],
            "properties":{
                "expressionEvaluationOptions": {
                    "scope": "Outer"
                },
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template":{
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0",
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                            "apiVersion": "2023-04-01",
                            "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
                            "location": "[parameters('rgLocation')]",
                            "sku": {
                                "name": "Standard_LRS"
                            },
                            "kind": "StorageV2",
                            "properties": {
                                "encryption": {
                                    "services": {
                                        "blob": {
                                            "enabled": true
                                        },
                                        "file": {
                                            "enabled": true
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
                                },
                                "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
                            "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
                            "name": "[variables('keyVaultName')]",
                            "location": "[parameters('rgLocation')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "tenantId": "[variables('tenantId')]",
                                "sku": {
                                    "name": "standard",
                                    "family": "A"
                                },
                                "enableSoftDelete": false,
                                "accessPolicies": []
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
                            "apiVersion": "2020-02-02-preview",
                            "name": "[variables('applicationInsightsName')]",
                            "location": "[parameters('rgLocation')]",
                            "kind": "web",
                            "properties": {
                                "Application_Type": "web"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries",
                            "apiVersion": "2022-02-01-preview",
                            "name": "[variables('containerRegistryName')]",
                            "sku": {
                                "name": "Standard"
                            },
                            "location": "[parameters('rgLocation')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "adminUserEnabled": false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces",
                            "apiVersion": "2020-08-01",
                            "name": "[variables('workSpaceFullName')]",
                            "location": "[parameters('rgLocation')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "friendlyName": "[variables('workSpaceFullName')]",
                                "storageAccount": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]",
                                "keyVault": "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', variables('keyVaultName'))]",
                                "applicationInsights": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('applicationInsightsName'))]",
                                "containerRegistry": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries', variables('containerRegistryName'))]"
                            },
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]",
                                "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', variables('keyVaultName'))]",
                                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('applicationInsightsName'))]",
                                "[resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries', variables('containerRegistryName'))]"
                            ],
                            "identity": {
                                "type": "systemAssigned"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

This template works fine for deploying a resource group and a storage account. However, I encounter errors when attempting to deploy multiple Azure Machine Learning services. My suspicion is that variables from the parent template are not being correctly passed to the child templates.
Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help.
I tried adjusting the expressionEvaluationOptions:
"expressionEvaluationOptions": {
    "scope": "Outer"
}

But received this error: Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/stmyprojectname' is not defined in the template.
"expressionEvaluationOptions": {
    "scope": "Inner"
}

Led to this error: Deployment template validation failed: 'The template variable 'storageAccountName' is not found. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-syntax-variables for usage details.
Here are the steps I've taken so far:

Tried both Inner and Outer scopes.
Successfully deployed a single resource within the group but failed with multiple resources.
Plan to use Azure DevOps for final deployment.


Does the issue occur when you deploy from local, or in Azure DevOps pipeline, or both?

The issue occurs when I use template on azure portal to validate the deployment template

So, you have never done an actual deployment neither from local nor in pipeline using the templates? Looks like, the problem is indeed on the templates itself. @Marvin

As mentioned, I've deployed using  the template, but it only works in the following scenarios:

Create the group and resources separately.
Create any resource except Azure Machine Learning.

The challenge arises because Azure Machine Learning needs to be linked to other resources, which causes issues with the variables.

Okay. So, the issue occurs when you deploy multiple resources using the template from local and in pipeline? @Marvin

I guess the issue occurs because variable('name') are not accesible inside of azure machine learning part (child 2) , as subscription level parameters and  variables (parent) are pass to the deployment part (child1),  but they cannot be pass to child2..

I solved the problem with Azure Resource Manager (ARM) templates where variables defined at the subscription level were not being correctly passed to nested deployments. Specifically:

Variables and parameters were being correctly passed to the first child deployment (Child1), which deployed a resource group and associated deployment.
However, variables were not being passed from Child1 to the second child deployment (Machine learning - Child2), which was supposed to use these variables.

Solution
To resolve this, I declared the required variables again in Child1. This allowed Child2 to access them, even though this approach isn’t the most elegant.
Alternative Solution
Another approach would be to create the resource group first and then pass the resource group name to target resources for creation. This can be done in two steps using Azure DevOps or your preferred DevOps tool.
I hope this helps anyone facing a similar issue
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "grPrefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "gr-mlw-"
        },
        "rgLocation": {
            "type": "string",
            "allowedValues": [
                "eastus2",
                "swedencentral",
                "taiwannorth"
            ],
            "defaultValue": "eastus2"
        },
        "workSpacePreffix": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "mlw-",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Machine Learning Workspace Prefix"
            }
        },
        "workSpaceName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "WorkSpace Name"
            }
        },
        "deploymentName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "IacDSGroupResourceDeploymentV1",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Deployment Name"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
        "hypenWorkSpaceName": "[toLower(replace(parameters('workSpaceName'), '_', '-'))]",
        "validWorkSpaceName": "[toLower(replace(variables('hypenWorkSpaceName'), '-', ''))]",
        "resourceGroupName": "[concat(parameters('grPrefix'), variables('hypenWorkSpaceName'))]",
        "workSpaceFullName": "[concat(parameters('workSpacePreffix'), variables('hypenWorkSpaceName'))]",
        "storageAccountName": "[concat('st', variables('validWorkSpaceName'))]",
        "keyVaultName": "[concat(variables('hypenWorkSpaceName'), '-kv')]",
        "applicationInsightsName": "[concat(variables('validWorkSpaceName'), '-ai')]",
        "containerRegistryName": "[concat(variables('validWorkSpaceName'), 'cr')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2024-03-01",
            "name": "[variables('resourceGroupName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('rgLocation')]",
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2024-03-01",
            "name": "[parameters('deploymentName')]",
            "resourceGroup": "[variables('resourceGroupName')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/', variables('resourceGroupName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "***expressionEvaluationOptions***": {
                    "scope": "Inner"
                },
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {
                        "storageAccountName": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "keyVaultName": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "applicationInsightsName": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "containerRegistryName": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "workSpaceFullName": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "location": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "tenantId": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                            "apiVersion": "2023-04-01",
                            "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
                            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                            "sku": {
                                "name": "Standard_LRS"
                            },
                            "kind": "StorageV2",
                            "properties": {
                                "encryption": {
                                    "services": {
                                        "blob": {
                                            "enabled": true
                                        },
                                        "file": {
                                            "enabled": true
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
                                },
                                "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
                            "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
                            "name": "[parameters('keyVaultName')]",
                            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "tenantId": "[parameters('tenantId')]",
                                "sku": {
                                    "name": "standard",
                                    "family": "A"
                                },
                                "enableSoftDelete": false,
                                "accessPolicies": []
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
                            "apiVersion": "2020-02-02-preview",
                            "name": "[parameters('applicationInsightsName')]",
                            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                            "kind": "web",
                            "properties": {
                                "Application_Type": "web"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries",
                            "apiVersion": "2022-02-01-preview",
                            "name": "[parameters('containerRegistryName')]",
                            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                            "sku": {
                                "name": "Standard"
                            },
                            "properties": {
                                "adminUserEnabled": false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces",
                            "apiVersion": "2020-08-01",
                            "name": "[parameters('workSpaceFullName')]",
                            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "friendlyName": "[parameters('workSpaceFullName')]",
                                "storageAccount": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]",
                                "keyVault": "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('keyVaultName'))]",
                                "applicationInsights": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('applicationInsightsName'))]",
                                "containerRegistry": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries', parameters('containerRegistryName'))]"
                            },
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]",
                                "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('keyVaultName'))]",
                                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('applicationInsightsName'))]",
                                "[resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries', parameters('containerRegistryName'))]"
                            ],
                            "identity": {
                                "type": "systemAssigned"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                ***"parameters"***: {
                    "storageAccountName": {
                        "value": "[variables('storageAccountName')]"
                    },
                    "keyVaultName": {
                        "value": "[variables('keyVaultName')]"
                    },
                    "applicationInsightsName": {
                        "value": "[variables('applicationInsightsName')]"
                    },
                    "containerRegistryName": {
                        "value": "[variables('containerRegistryName')]"
                    },
                    "workSpaceFullName": {
                        "value": "[variables('workSpaceFullName')]"
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "value": "[parameters('rgLocation')]"
                    },
                    "tenantId": {
                        "value": "[variables('tenantId')]"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

